# How to create a direct link to access a specific Google Maps API V3 marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, hyperlink, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm creating a ASP.NET MVC3 website using a Google Maps API V3 with a lot of markers. Each marker has an InfoWindow with some information about this place.

I wish each marker have a direct link to access my website directly on this marker, like http://www.mywebsite/1589. So the user could access the website with the map centered on marker 1589 and its InfoWindows would be open.

The markers are already on the map and their InfoWindow are already displaying informations, but I have no idea how to create a direct link to the marker... Could anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [example 1](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomarker.html?marker=1), [example 2](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomarker.html?id=Marker%20Two), ported to v3 from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial examples on [this page of his tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/linktothis.htm)

Comment: @geocodezip The examples from your website seems to be exactly what I'd like ; however, I'm not sure how to do this. Do I need to create my link like mywebsite.com/1539 ; request the lat/lng of this marker, then center my map on this marker and open the InfoWindow ? Or, if I'm wrong, could you post a sample of code ?

Comment: View the source of the examples.  You need to write code to process the query string in the URL.

Comment: @geocodezip sorry I didn't event think about looking source code. I think I'll be able to write what I need, I will looking this deeper tonight and told you if everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key pieces are:

- parse the query string

  ```
  // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
  var query = location.search.substring(1);

  // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
    // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();

    // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
    if (argname == "id") {id = unescape(value);}
    if (argname == "marker") {index = parseFloat(value);}
  }
  ```
- open the infowindow after loading the markers, if a parameter is passed

  ```
    // ========= If a parameter was passed, open the info window ==========
    if (id) {
      if (idmarkers[id]) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(idmarkers[id],"click");
      } else {
        alert("id "+id+" does not match any marker");
      }
    }
    if (index > -1) {
      if (index < gmarkers.length) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[index],"click");
      } else {
        alert("marker "+index+" does not exist");
      }
    }
  ```
- you might also want the "link to" functionality in [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomap.html?id=Marker%20One&lat=43.784976&lng=-81.018677&zoom=7&type=m), which sets up the query string